# Rotate TextView without rotating any text

Tags: android, textview, rotateanimation

I have TextView which is rotating, but I want to rotate only the background of TextView not a text, I tried to put TextView inside the LinearLayout but still it is rotating with text, so how can I solve this?

My xml code is below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRotate"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gif1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_image"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.rotate);
        animFadein.setFillAfter(true);
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

txtVibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtRotate.startAnimation(animFadein);
            }
        });
```

rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="6000"
            android:repeatMode="restart"
            android:repeatCount="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
    </set>
```

Comment: You can make your textview background transparent and create view behind textview which will be holding your textView's background and then animate this view.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working because view is holding TextView so View is rotate with TextView!! Any another idea about it?

Comment: It shouldnt be holding textView, look at @Abhishek Patel answer

Comment: use `android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable` to rotate the background

Answer (score 1):

Use XML below code and use TextView with this id---android:id="@+id/txtRotate" for animating text background.
and use another textview for text.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRotate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one parent `view` and apply the animation to layout instead of the `TextView`

```
 <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/fmlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRotate"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gif1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_image"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

> rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="6000"
            android:repeatMode="restart"
            android:repeatCount="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
    </set>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
 animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.rotate);
            animFadein.setFillAfter(true);
            animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

    txtVibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
// here change the code and apply animation on framelayout
                }
            });
```

Comment: @komal please look into my ans

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your xml like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlImages"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRotate"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivBackPic"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivBackPic"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivBackPic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivBackPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and apply animation for  `ivBackPic` `Imageview` it may be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had looking for the solution on same question and finally it is resolved.
If we will rotate the view by 180f by using any method this will also rotate the text. Simply rotate it to 360f and the same will show the correct text. I am using following code:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "rotationY", 0f, 360f);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.start();
```